# Xamarin forms Passing values from Pages with navigation

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Initially, I did the `navigation.popasync` on second page back to main page and passed in the values inside the `navigation.pushasync`. However, now I want to go to a third page, and then do a update of time stamp `lblEndDT` in third page. I want to update `lblEndDT` on main page but `btnDone` in Third Page. How do I pass the value from main page to third page?

Main Page

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public string mainpagevalue;
    int offlinecount = 0;
    int onlinecount = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnOffline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        offlinecount++;

        //Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this, lblEndDT));

        Navigation.PushAsync(new OfflinePage(this, lblEndDT, btnOnline));


        if (offlinecount == 1)
        {
            string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;

        }


    }

    private void btnOnline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onlinecount++;


        Navigation.PushAsync(new OnlinePage());


        if (onlinecount == 1)
        {
            string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;

        }
    }
  }
}
```

main page xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <!--OFFLINE TOOL-->
    <ImageButton x:Name="btnOffline" IsEnabled="True" Source="@drawable/offlinetool.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="btnOffline_Clicked"/>
    <Label Text="Offline Tool" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>

    <Label Text="Start Date Time:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Label Text="End Date Time:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="7,40,0,0"/>

    <Label x:Name="lblStartDT" Text="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblEndDT" Text="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,40,0,0"/>


    <!--ONLINE TOOL-->
    <ImageButton x:Name="btnOnline" Source="@drawable/ot.png" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsEnabled="False" Clicked="btnOnline_Clicked"/>
    <Label Text="Online Tool" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Margin="19,0,0,0"/>

    <Label Text="Start Date Time:" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Label Text="End Date Time:" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="3" Margin="7,40,0,0"/>
    <Label Text="Status:" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="3" Margin="58,0,0,0" />

    <Label x:Name="lblOnlineStartDT" Text="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="8"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblOnlineEndDT" Text="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="8" Margin="0,40,0,0"/>
    <Label x:Name="txtOnlineStatus" Text="NOT STARTED" TextColor="Red" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="9"/>





</Grid>
```

Offline Page

```
public partial class OfflinePage : ContentPage
{
    Label offlineEndDT;
    MainPage mainpage;
    ImageButton btnonline;
    public OfflinePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public OfflinePage(MainPage mpage, Label endDT, ImageButton onlineimage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainpage = mpage;
        offlineEndDT = endDT;
        btnonline = onlineimage;

    }
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.offlineDonecount++;

        if (App.offlineDonecount == 1)
        {
            string edt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            offlineEndDT.Text = edt;
            mainpage.mainpagevalue = offlineEndDT.Text;


        }

        btnonline.Source = "onlinetool";
        btnonline.IsEnabled = true;

        Navigation.PopAsync();


    }
  }
}
```

Online Page

```
public partial class OnlinePage : ContentPage
{
    public OnlinePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ThirdPage());
    }
  }
}
```

Third Page

```
public partial class ThirdPage : ContentPage
{
    public ThirdPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void BtnDone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You could try using `Xamarin.Essentials` by saving and retriving the value of time stamp from wherever you want using [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android). Also you could try using [Messaging Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) but it's not recomended.

Comment: Hi I tried to search up on Xamarin.Essentials but I am unsure how do I use it. Am I suppose to call this function in the Main page and use it on the third page?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

Create the TimeStamp model with Online, Offline Start and End time.

```
 public class TimeStamp
{
    public string OnlineStartTime { get; set; }
    public string OnlineEndTime { get; set; }
    public string OfflineStartTime { get; set; }
    public string OfflineEndTime { get; set; }
}
```

**MainPage:**

Xaml:

```
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--  OFFLINE TOOL  -->
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnOffline"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Clicked="btnOffline_Clicked"
            IsEnabled="True"
            Source="monkeyicon.png" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="15,0,0,0"
            Text="Offline Tool" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="Start Date Time:" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Margin="0,40,0,0"
            Text="End Date Time:" />

        <Label
            x:Name="lblStartDT"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="4"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Text="{Binding OfflineStartTime}" />
        <Label
            x:Name="lblEndDT"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="4"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="0,40,0,0"
            Text="{Binding OfflineEndTime}" />


        <!--  ONLINE TOOL  -->
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnOnline"
            Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.Column="1"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Clicked="btnOnline_Clicked"
            IsEnabled="True"
            Source="star_small.png" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="9"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="19,0,0,0"
            Text="Online Tool" />

        <Label
            Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="Start Date Time:" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Margin="7,40,0,0"
            Text="End Date Time:" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="9"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Margin="58,0,0,0"
            Text="Status:" />

        <Label
            x:Name="lblOnlineStartDT"
            Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="4"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Text="{Binding OnlineStartTime}" />
        <Label
            x:Name="lblOnlineEndDT"
            Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="4"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="0,40,0,0"
            Text="{Binding OnlineEndTime}" />
        <Label
            x:Name="txtOnlineStatus"
            Grid.Row="9"
            Grid.Column="4"
            Text="NOT STARTED"
            TextColor="Red" />
    </Grid>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public string mainpagevalue;
    int offlinecount = 0;
    int onlinecount = 0;
    public static TimeStamp timeStamp = new TimeStamp();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void btnOnline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onlinecount++;
        if (onlinecount == 1)
        {
            string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            lblOnlineStartDT.Text = currentDT;
            timeStamp.OnlineStartTime = currentDT;
        }
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new OnlinePage());
    }
    private void btnOffline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        offlinecount++;
        //Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this, lblEndDT));
        Navigation.PushAsync(new OfflinePage(this, lblEndDT, btnOnline));
        if (offlinecount == 1)
        {
            string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;
            timeStamp.OfflineStartTime = currentDT;
        }
    }
}
```

**OfflinePage:**

```
 public partial class OfflinePage : ContentPage
{
    Label offlineEndDT;
    MainPage mainpage;
    ImageButton btnonline;
    public OfflinePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public OfflinePage(MainPage mpage, Label endDT, ImageButton onlineimage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainpage = mpage;
        offlineEndDT = endDT;
        btnonline = onlineimage;
    }
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.offlineDonecount++;

        if (App.offlineDonecount == 1)
        {
            string edt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            offlineEndDT.Text = edt;
            mainpage.mainpagevalue = offlineEndDT.Text;
            MainPage.timeStamp.OfflineEndTime = edt;
        }         
        btnonline.IsEnabled = true;
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

**OnlinePage:**

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ThirdPage());
    }
```

**ThirdPage:**

```
private async void BtnDone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.timeStamp.OnlineEndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
        mainPage.BindingContext = MainPage.timeStamp;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(mainPage);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for the help, but instead of replacing the time stamp with update click event, I would like to have another label that displays the update button time stamp. I tried editing my codes, but I am not sure how do I bind from third page using main page's variables.

Comment: I changed my code accordingly but I realize I don't want to push to a new page, but redirect to the previous page. Because I will be recording a set of start and end time stamp, if I push to a new page all my previous records will be gone.

Comment: Could you provide your code? And mode details of what you wnat?

Comment: Hi i updated my code! If you run my code, you can see when u press btnOffline, it will record the start time stamp. after you click done, it records the end date time. So for OnlinePage, after clicking one, it will redirect to third page. So on the third page, I want to record the end time stamp

Comment: Hello, I tested with my code but I realise I don't want to go to a new main page, but popasync back the main page. How do I do it? Is it possible to do a navigation pop async?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pop from ThirdPage to OnlinePage and set the time stamp you get from the ThirdPage to MainPage?

Comment: MainPage > Online Page > ThirdPage > MainPage. So from ThirdPage back to MainPage, I want all my other values to stay. When I used your code, it navigates back to a new MainPage, and my other timestamp went missing. For example my current code, there is btnOffline and btnOnline right? It will record down the timestamp for btnOffline when clicked. Then when I click btnOnline to OnlinePage, then to ThirdPage, and back to MainPage, my btnOffline timestamp is missing.

Comment: ohh..sorry, i miss the offlinePage. I will check my code again and feeedback ASAP.

Comment: Hi I think this method does not work for my application because I am not just getting the timestamp, but as well as changing image and enabling the image button in sequence. Now when I go back to MainPage from ThirdPage, it will only keep the timestamp. If I use your method, I think I will need to bind every data... :/ not sure if binding everything is possible

Comment: BtnOffline, BtnOnline and more will go by sequence. Only when user is done with btnOffline, I will update the status from 'Not Started' to 'Started' + the TimeStamp, then BtnOnline will be enabled (I will change the image source as well), so on and so forth for the rest of the buttons I have in my code. On the last button, it will be the one that requires ThirdPage. So at the end of everything, when I go back to MainPage from ThirdPage, everything went back to how it looked like at the start except the TimeStamp (if i follow ur binding)

Comment: When pass value and need update, binding could do that. You could create the model with the value you want to change. It would be okay.

Comment: Is it not possible to just update the time stamp from Third Page and display the changes in Main Page? :(

Comment: When you want to update, you need to pass the updated value from ThirdPage to MainPage. Binding could do that, you could try.